# Google Cloud Dataflow streaming pipeline with PubSubIO resource setup failed

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187665/unable-to-create-pipeline-with-pubsubio-read-set-up-of-resource-failed) question, but it didn't solve my problem.

I read from a PubSub topic in my Dataflow topology, but I am always getting the error of "resource setup failure":

[image: stack trace]

Even if I have already enabled all of the Google Cloud APIs for the project.

Do you have any ideas? Could it be some issue with credentials?
Where can I get a more meaningful error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create the topics by hand.

Dataflow automatically creates the subscriptions, not topics.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! But that error message can definitely be better -- I've filed a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Frances! It was a bug indeed? I thought I misunderstood the documentation. It clearly states: "When you provide a topic name, Dataflow automatically creates a subscription to that topic for you".

Comment: Aaaaaa ok, you filed a bug for the poor error message.